# Adding dependency injection gives exception in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am getting the following exception. Why is it and how can I solve this?

In `SMSService.cs` when I comment on the constructor it starts to work, but I will require to access `ISMSSender` from it.

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
> constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType: Authentication.API.Repository.Interface.ISMSService
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> Authentication.API.Repository.SMSService': Unable to resolve service
> for type 'SMSSender.API.Repository.Interface.ISMSSender' while
> attempting to activate 'Authentication.API.Repository.SMSService'.)'

**Authentication.API.Repository.SMSService**

```
public class SMSService : ISMSService
{
    private readonly ISMSSender _smsSender;

    public SMSService(ISMSSender smsSender)
    {
        _smsSender = smsSender;
    }
}
```

**Startup**
...

```
         services.AddTransient<ISMSService, SMSService>();

         ...
```

**SMSSender.API.Repository.Interface.ISMSSender**

```
public interface ISMSSender
{
    Task<SMSUser> SendSMS(SMSUser prospectiveUser);
}
```

**SMSSender.API.Repository.Interface.SMSSender**

```
public class SMSSender : ISMSSender
{
    public async Task<SMSUser> SendSMS(SMSUser sMSUser)
    { }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you didn't register the SMSSender (you did the service):

```
services.AddTransient<ISMSService, SMSService>();
services.AddTransient<ISMSSender, SMSSender>();
```

Comment: Do I have to ? It comes from another project?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: You are building your DI container in this stage. You are telling it which services implement each interface. Without this, there is no way to know which service to resolve based on the interface.